# Trying to pass details from last order event/observers

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, php

I am getting this issue now. I can pass the productId but the foreach it looks like it does not work, When customer order 2 items the result i get is just the last item productId.

Here is the code:

```
class Order_OrderExport_Model_Export
{

    public function exportOrder($order,$sku) 
    {
        $dirPath = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'export';

        if (!is_dir($dirPath)) {
            mkdir($dirPath, 0777, true);
        }

        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {

        $data = array(

            'getIncrementId'        => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'created_at'            => $order->getCreatedAt(),
            'customer_id'           => $order->getCustomerId(),
            'customer_firstname'    => $order->getCustomerFirstname(),
            'customer_lastname'     => $order->getCustomerLastname(),
            'customer_email'        => $order->getCustomerEmail(),

            'telephone'             => $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone(),
            'street'                => $order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet(),
            'get_city'              => $order->getBillingAddress()->getCity(),
            'postcode'              => $order->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode(),
            'region'                => $order->getBillingAddress()->getRegion(),
            'get_country'           => $order->getBillingAddress()->getCountry(),

            'tax_amount'            => $order->getTaxAmount(),
            'shipping_amount'       => $order->getShippingAmount(),
            'remote_ip'             => $order->getRemoteIp(),

            'total_qty_ordered'     => $order->getTotalQtyOrdered(),
            'subtotal'              => $order->getSubtotal(),
            'grand_total'           => $order->getGrandTotal(),
            'order_currency_code'   => $order->getOrderCurrencyCode(),

    //Here is the output of the items

            'item'                  => $item->getProductId(),

            );


        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
        array_walk_recursive($data, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
        file_put_contents(
        $dirPath. DS .$order->getIncrementId().'.xml', 
        $xml->asXML()

        );
     }

}
```

The XML i am outputting display only on product. Thank you

Comment: which event is observed by `exportOrder`?

Comment: This event: sales_order_place_after

Comment: do a `print_r($order->getData())` ... what do you get in there? Can you see the fields you were looking for?

Comment: Try with `sales_order_place_before` event

Comment: When i export in xml there are everything beside Address,City,Phone kind of personal information this happen when i print_r($order->getData()) too, i can't even get the product name just the entity_id of the product

Comment: Sorry the entity_id is not of the product but the entity_id of the order. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address details are stored separately. Try with either

```
$order->getBillingAddress()->getCity()
```

or

```
$order->getShippingAddress()->getCity()
```

depending on your requirements.

Comment: you are genius, that worked. What i did til now was this far $order->getShippingAddress() and no result the ->getCity did the trick. I guess is the same thing for product details too? Thank you very much

Comment: For order items you want something like foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item){ $item->getName();}

Comment: Do i really need a foreach because i have an event sales_order_place_after or you mean because customer may order more than one item? Thank you

Comment: You asked about the ordered items - so yes the foreach is needed since an order might contain more than 1 ordered item. If you really wanted to get the original product you would additionally need to use $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

Comment: At Fooman, Please i have edited the code and trying to output the productid. I get only the last productid on the xml result not multiple orders. Do you have any idea of this issue Fooeman? I have updated the code above. I must miss something there. Thank you

Comment: @DanielDake the foreach should only be for the items not the whole order info. Your current code overwrites the last entry. Please also do not completely change the question since now the answers and comments can't be easily understood. In the future create a new question instead.

Comment: Yes you right. Thank you for your suggestions.